# SharePoint 2013 Alert Me Redirecting issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm working on SharePoint Site with 3 type of Access.
This is an example from the AAM:

1. Default URL  (EX: http:// test-myPortal-Web:80)
2. Internal URL (EX: http://internal.myPortal.com)
3. Extranet URL (EX: https://portal.myPortal.com)  >> "*Extented Web Application* "

So when i logged as **https://portal.myPortal.com** and create an Alert to a specific list, i noticed that the email has an invalid URL.

It Contain in the subject an email redirect to "http:// test-myPortal-Web:80/.." which isn't my case!

I want to redirect to **https://portal.myPortal.com/..** as the access type

Any idea to resolve it ?

***Snapshot from the email received:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default in the alert emails sent by SharePoint it will always contain the URL which is in Default zone in AAM. 

It does not matters if you are logged in to the site with some other URL of another AAM zone.

Reference: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88203/urls-used-in-alert-emails